# get the inbuilt function's method name which is passed as an argument and call inside function body

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, logging

I'm looking to generalize the logging activity in python in my work.

Rather than calling logger.debug(), logger.info(), logger.warning() etc, I'm thinking of writing a template function which get all the necessary arguments to call either debug , info or warning etc.

Example:

```
def logging_template(logger_name, level, message):
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.##level(message) //Here if level is passed as debug then logger.debug should be called. If level is passed as info then logger.info should be called.
Similarly if warning or error or critical is passed then corresponding logger calls should be triggered.
```

I'm not interested on IF-ELSE block or condition checks. ##level should be replaced by the argument i'm passing.

Comment: Are you looking for [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)?

Comment: Is `level` a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getattr, for example:

```
def logging_template(logger_name, level, message):
    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    getattr(logger, level)(message)
```

Explanation:

getattr(logger, level) returns the function logger.debug if level is the string "debug". It returns logger.error if level is the string "error", and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `logger.log` method? It takes a variable level and would seem to do the same as you're trying to do here.